# QAbstractItemModel does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

I've been using Qt5 on MS Windows 7 for a while. All of the sudden I cannot compile even the default scaffold for a GUI (Forms) application. I get the following error:

[image]

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

project.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = RagnSells3
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow" >
  <property name="geometry" >
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle" >
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar" />
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar" />
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget" />
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar" />
 </widget>
 <layoutDefault spacing="6" margin="11" />
 <pixmapfunction></pixmapfunction>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: What is the code that caused such errors?

Comment: looks like there's a problem with the `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro of Qt. Try checking the definition in `qglobal.h` or just try reinstalling Qt.

Comment: A re-install of Qt worked. Might need to set the source dir to read only. Still, imho, this is a bug.